# Проблема с подключением к игровому серверу в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ufw

На Ubuntu 16.04 запущено ПО игрового сервера, написанное на PHP 7. Но проблема не в ПО, а в системе. Клиент игры не может соединиться с сервером. В логах сервера нет информации о том, что к нему пытаются подключиться, а клиент не может получить ответа от сервера. Однако эта проблема на некоторое время решается очень странным способом. Стоит зайти на веб сервер apache, который запущен на этом же VPS, так сразу же происходит подключение клиента к серверу. Именно это обстоятельство заставляет меня думать, что проблема с сетевыми настройками системы.

ПО сервера - PocketMine, запущен на 19131 порту. Порт был открыт с помощью `sudo ufw allow 19131`. Вывод netstat следующий:

[image: sudo netstat -anltp]

Сталкивался ли кто-то с подобным, когда подключение удаётся только после захода на сайт в браузере? Как эти действия могут быть связаны между собой?